# Как сделать так, что бы активность автоматически запускалась при включении телефона?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Пишу экран блокировки, имеется главная активность (`MainActivity`), содержащая настройки экрана блокировки и сама активность экрана блокировки (`LockScreenActivity`), так вот: как сделать так, что бы активность экрана блокировки запускалась автоматически при включении телефона? Т.е. что бы она постоянно была запущена, пока её в настройках (`MainActivity`) не отключит пользователь?

Comment: Владислав, если вы нашли решение - приведите его в качестве ответа. Это поможет будущим посетителям.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте Broadcast Receiver - механизм, реагирующий на широковещательные сообщения. Вкратце - широковещатеьное сообщение может быть например каким нибудь системым событием, на которое может отреагировать BroadcastReceiver установленного приложения. Включение телефона является широковещательным сообщением, так что можно легко обрабатывать это событие

Comment: Спасибо, изначально и использовал BroadcastReciver, только изначально не сработало, т.к. не сделал проверку на событие включение телефона, поэтому и решил тут спросить)